# Does Win 2008 r2 x64 server come with .net 3 sp1 package already installed?

Tags: .net-3.5, installation, windows-server-2008, servicepacks

same as in title? I have a test server with mentioned OS and my app is .net 3.5 based. I do want to know if win 2008 r2 comes with service pack 1 for .net 3.5 from the box. And does it come with .net 3.5 sp1 family update as WELL, since after I downloaded the update, the installer says I do not have software required to update. Could some win 2008 guru perhaps explain it to me?
thanks
luke

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Server 2008 R2 does come with .NET 3.5 SP1, however it is not an installed feature by default.  You can find the [details for installing it here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151115034019/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/sqlblog/archive/2010/01/08/how-to-install-net-framework-3-5-sp1-on-windows-server-2008-r2-environments.aspx) (because for R2, the directions are different than they previously have been)

Answer (score 1):

I think it includes .Net 3.5 SP1, but that it's not installed by default but that you can install it by running `servermanagercmd -install Net-Framework`.

Answer (score 0):

After some googling it indeed includes .net 3.5 SP1 .net 3.0 Sp2 and .net 2.0 SP2 + family update for .net + hotfixes

Turns out that win 208 r2 x64 includes .net 3.5 SP1 with family update and a hotfix that makes Linq work with constraints to keys that are not primary keys, but THIS IS REALLY hard to come by:)